# How do I override hiera_data in rspec-puppet?

Tags: rspec, tdd, puppet, hiera, rspec-puppet

Lets say I have the following tests:

```
context 'test' do
  let(:hiera_data) { { :number => '2' } }

  it { should have_module__define_resource_count(2) }
end

context 'test2' do
  let(:hiera_data) { { :number => '10' } }

  it { should have_module__define_resource_count(10) }
end
```

The first test passes, but when the second test is ran it fails, because the hiera variable `number` is still 2.

It seems that `let(:hiera_data)` is unable to override the previous declared variable.

According to [this readme](https://github.com/mthibaut/hiera-puppet-helper) it should work if the hiera data is set in different files, but it does not work.

How do I test hiera multiple times in one specfile?

Comment: Can you paste the complete test somewhere?

Comment: @FelixFrank The question has been updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, and was stumped for a while. Eventually I found out that the hiera information is. You can fix it like so:

```
let(:facts) {{ :cache_bust => Time.now }}
```

So for example:

Puppet code:

```
class example::bar {
  notify { 'bar': message => hiera('bar_message') }
}
```

rspec-puppet code:

```
describe "example::bar" do

  let(:facts) {{ :cache_bust => Time.now }}

  describe "first in-line hiera_data test with a" do
    let(:hiera_data) { { :bar_message => "a" } }
    it { should contain_notify("bar").with_message("a") }
  end

  describe "second in-line hiera_data test with b" do
    let(:hiera_data) { { :bar_message => "b" } }
    it { should contain_notify("bar").with_message("b") }
  end
end
```

This works! [I have a PR to add it to the docs.](https://github.com/bobtfish/hiera-puppet-helper/pull/3) The botfish fork is the most recently maintained fork of hiera-puppet-helper ([see the note on the original](https://github.com/amfranz/rspec-hiera-puppet/blob/master/README.md))